# Could not find module 'System.Console.Readline' in Haskell

Tags: haskell, readline

When I try to execute `:load hello.hs` in ghci, I get the following error:

```
Could not find module "System.Console.Readline"
```

Since this is a System module, I thought this would work. How do I fix this?

Comment: If you're just using readline because it's the first you've heard of then look at / consider using haskeline too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your system, you will want to install the `readline` Haskell package.

To do so, make sure that you have GNU readline actually installed via `apt-get` (Ubuntu), macports (Mac OSX), Cygwin (Windows?), or whatever your favourite package manager is on your platform.

If you have Haskell's `cabal` installed, simply run
`cabal install readline` and hopefully everything will compile, and you can try and run your `hello.hs` again!

If you don't have `cabal`, it's a sort of command line interface for grabbing and managing packages from HackageDB. Follow the instructions on [haskell.org/cabal](http://www.haskell.org/cabal) to get `cabal`. It's pretty handy to have, if not essential :D

Answer (score 4):

You need to install the [readline](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/readline)-package with

```
cabal install readline
```

Answer (score 3):

When you want to use `brew` for `deadline` on Mac OS X.

1. Install readline: `brew install readline`
2. `cabal install readline --extra-include-dirs=/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.3.8/include/ --extra-lib-dirs=/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.3.8/lib/ --configure-option=--with-readline-includes=/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.3.8/inc‌​lude/ --configure-option=--with-readline-libraries=/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.3.8/lib/`

Reference: [How do you install the haskell readline library on Mac OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8291137/how-do-you-install-the-haskell-readline-library-on-mac-osx)