# How do you install the haskell readline library on Mac OSX?

Tags: haskell, readline

I'm referring to the [haskell readline library wrapper](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/readline-1.0.1.0) to the [c readline library](http://www.gnu.org/directory/readline.html).

`cabal install readline` output below:

```
$ cabal install readline
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring readline-1.0.1.0...
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for GNUreadline.framework... checking for readline... no
checking for tputs in -lncurses... yes
checking for readline in -lreadline... yes
checking for rl_readline_version... yes
checking for rl_begin_undo_group... no
configure: error: readline not found, so this package cannot be built
See `config.log' for more details.
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
readline-1.0.1.0 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

I have the c readline library installed via macports (using `sudo port install readline`), but I still get the same error while trying to install the haskell readline library.

Comment: http://www.haskell.org/cabal/FAQ.html

Comment: If you installed `readline` with `port` then why do you need to try and install it with `cabal`?

Comment: The `readline` c library is installed with port, but I can't install the `readline` haskell library. I've clarified the question to make that clear.

Comment: Are there separate library and -dev library packages with port? If so, you'll need to install the -dev version as well.

Comment: @DanielWagner There doesn't appear to be one.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If your MacPorts installation uses the default paths for installed files, try specifying where to look for the C headers and libraries:

```
cabal install readline --extra-include-dirs=/opt/local/include \
--extra-lib-dirs=/opt/local/lib
```

**Update 2x**: On my machine with GNU Readline installed via Homebrew rather than MacPorts, it looks like the `configure` script for the Haskell `readline` library needs some non-standard flags to properly find its bearings. If the above doesn't work, try this:

```
cabal install readline --extra-include-dirs=/opt/local/include \
--extra-lib-dirs=/opt/local/lib \
--configure-option=--with-readline-includes=/opt/local/include \
--configure-option=--with-readline-libraries=/opt/local/lib
```

Comment: Thanks, I got it working. I used the command: `sudo port install readline +universal` to install readline, and the command `cabal install readline --extra-include-dirs=/opt/local/include --extra-lib-dirs=/opt/local/lib --configure-option=--with-readline-includes=/opt/local/include --configure-option=--with-readline-libraries=/opt/local/lib` to install the haskell readline library.

Comment: Of course; it needs to have both to actually link against once `configure` has run. Updated to reflect the final mouthful of a command

Comment: The readline formula is keg only, therefore I had to add full path to the keg like so: `cabal install readline --extra-include-dirs=/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.2.4/include/ --extra-lib-dirs=/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.2.4/lib/ --configure-option=--with-readline-includes=/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.2.4/include/ --configure-option=--with-readline-libraries=/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.2.4/lib/`

Comment: I needed : cabal install readline --extra-include-dirs=/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.2.4/include/ --extra-lib-dirs=/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.2.4/lib/ --configure-option=--with-readline-includes=/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.2.4/include/readline --configure-option=--with-readline-libraries=/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.2.4/lib/

Comment: Has anyone been successful doing this with `stack install`?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up following the instructions here http://fp.okeefecreations.com/2010/08/installing-haskell-bindings-to-readline.html in order to get it working on my homebrew installation of readline.  The only modification I had to make was to adjust the version of readline listed in the path.

I know this is a similar solution to acfoltzer's but I don't have the rep to add a comment there or either I just can't figure out how to comment. :)

Comment: $ cabal install readline --configure-option=--with-readline-libraries="/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.2.4/lib" --configure-option=--with-readline-includes="/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.2.4/include" For latest

Comment: The link in your answer is broken.

Answer (score 0):

If you used `brew`, here's the command you can use which is very similar to the above and you have to replace the version I'm stated with the one you have on your system i.e. `7.0.5`

```
cabal install readline --extra-include-dirs=/usr/local/Cellar/readline/7.0.5/include --extra-lib-dirs=/usr/local/Cellar/readline/7.0.5/lib --configure-option=--with-readline-includes=/usr/local/Cellar/readline/7.0.5/include --configure-option=--with-readline-libraries=/usr/local/Cellar/readline/7.0.5/lib
```